# Не могу придумать цикл для создания массива

Tags: java

```
package BaseCode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Task03_Self {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] list1 = new int[]{2, 4, 7, 5, 7};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list1));
        int[] list2 = new int[5];

        list2[0] = list1[0];
        list2[1] = list1[0] + list1[1];
        list2[2] = list1[0] + list1[1] + list1[2];
        list2[3] = list1[0] + list1[1] + list1[2] + list1[3];
        list2[4] = list1[0] + list1[1] + list1[2] + list1[3] + list1[4];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list2));
    }
}
```

Никак не могу допереть как это циклом обернуть

Задание: 
По заданному списку list1(n) построить список list2(n),

для которого:

list2[0]=list1[0];

list2[1] = list1[0]+list1[1] и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый элемент присвоить явно

```
list2[0]=list1[0];
```

Далее в цикле складывать текущий из `list1` с предыдущим из `list2`:

```
list2[i] = list2[i-1] + list1[i];
```